# "Кот мурлычет" или "кот мурлыкает"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как лучше и грамотнее сказать: "Кот мурлычет" или "кот мурлыкает"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: мурлычет. Форма "мурлыкает" - просторечие.

Answer (score 1):

Словарь Евгеньевой обе формы дает как равноправные, без помет. Этот глагол входит в категорию т.наз. *изобилующих*  (типа *плескать, капать, кудахтать, колыхать, махать, рыскать* и др.), дающих две формы при спряжении. Одна из них может быть стилистически окрашенной. В других случаях различие может носить смысловой характер.

Comment: Евгеньева в явном меньшинстве.   
В другой ситуации признал бы приоритет одного словарного разрешения перед всеми запрещениями, но тут позволю себе усомниться в силу непрофильности словаря. Надо орфоэпические смотреть. А у меня сейчас под рукой нету. Попозже в Аванесове посмотрю.